# How to enable logging in jetty?

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to debug my case, where simple ActiveWeb application is not running under Jetty. It behaves as if no any classes for request processing exist and return error 404.

The question is not about ActiveWeb. It is about Jetty. How to find out, that having some web application, Jetty has fond annotated class and will execute it on HTTP request?

Currently I have downloaded Jetty and it works. Unfortunately, it does no logging. Nothing is displayed in `stdout` or `stderr` and no files appear in `logs` subdirectory at the moment, when 404 error returns.

How to enable logging in jetty?

Documentation here http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html and here http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html is not clear and controversal.

For example, first page says Jetty does not use any Java loggin framework, but also requires one to select one. The second page provides some example of configuration, but does not say, where this code should be put.

Answer (score 39):

### Updated (July 2020) answer for Jetty 10 and newer

Starting with Jetty 10.0.0, there is no longer a "Jetty Logging" facade.
The Jetty project [has moved to using SLF4J 2.0 only](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4572).

### The original answer for Jetty 9 and older

The documentation is correct, as the term "Java Logging Framework" is often associated with modern logging frameworks like java.util.logging, slf4j, logback, log4j, commons-logging, logkit, etc.

This is correct, Jetty does not use any of those.

Jetty logging predates *ALL* of those efforts at standardized logging frameworks. (Jetty, and its logging layer was created in 1995)

This is what Jetty logging does (and [is documented](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-logging) at the documentation site) with regards to setup and configuration.

**Default behavior:**

- If [slf4j](http://slf4j.org/) is present in your classpath, it will emit logging events to slf4j to handle using the [Slf4jLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Slf4jLog.html) handler.
- Fallback to [StdErrLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/StdErrLog.html), emitting to System.err.

**To configure:**

- Specify the logging implementation you want it to use.
  Choices are:

  - [StdErrLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/StdErrLog.html)
  - [Slf4jLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Slf4jLog.html)
  - [JavaUtilLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/JavaUtilLog.html)

This can be accomplished in 3 different ways

1. Using a system property to set the logging impl

```sh
# 3 different options
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
```

2. Using the `jetty-logging.properties` self discover/configuration found from classpath.

[Example from jetty project itself](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-websocket/websocket-common/src/test/resources/jetty-logging.properties):

```sh
# Configure for System.err output
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
# Configure StdErrLog to log all jetty namespace at default of WARN or above
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN
# Configure StdErrLog to log websocket specific namespace at DEBUG or above
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

3. Using code to set [`Log.setLog(Logger)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.html#setLog(org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger))

This is particularly useful for those using [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty)

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog;

Log.setLog(new StdErrLog());
```

**Advice and Notes:**

The output of your Jetty server startup will give you hints about the logging implementation it is using.

*Normal / Default behavior:*

```
2014-09-11 10:48:38.726:INFO::main: Logging initialized @378ms
2014-09-11 10:48:39.067:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/Users/joakim/Code/Jetty/distros/jetty-distribution-9.2.1.v20140609/demo-base/webapps/] at interval 1
```

Notice that this has either no namespace declaration, or heavily abbreviated namespace in its output.   This tells me that the `StdErrLog` is in use.

*If slf4j is in use:*

```
10:50:18.871 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @352ms
10:50:19.102 [main] INFO  o.e.j.d.p.ScanningAppProvider - Deployment monitor [file:/Users/joakim/Code/Jetty/distros/jetty-distribution-9.2.1.v20140609/demo-base/webapps/] at interval 1
```

This is a default [Console appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) output for `slf4j` -> `logback`.  The overall structure here is very different that what the `StdErrLog` produces, so I can now tell that jetty is emitting via the `Slf4jLog` implementation.

Comment: Great answer, but even after trying all these I am unable to see debug log messages. I tried setting debug using the logger.setDebugEnabled(true) as well, but when i do `logger.debug("some message", new Exception")` I get no output. Works when I use info() or warn() though.

Comment: Configuration of the logging levels is determined by the logger implementation you choose.  With StdErrLog its properties in a `jetty-logging.properties`.  With java.util.logging its done entirely in java.util.logging, With slf4j, its the chosen slf4j implementation you have chosen (such as slf4j-log12 would mean your log4j.xml controls it) etc ...

Comment: to make slf4j working add appropriate jars to lib folder. My jetty 9.3.8 has only sfl4j-api and Slf4jLog doc tells that by default NOPlogger is used.

Comment: So, If I know for sure that my jetty is using Slfj4jLog how I can easily modify log levels? Via log4j.properties file?

Comment: @zygimantus please open a new question, or look for an existing one (your topic should have many answers by now).

Comment: What package on maven repo contains org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log??

Comment: @ScottF Just a tip but you can search the maven central repo by classname - https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I've solved it by following the recommendations in the documentation page ([Default Logging with Jetty’s StdErrLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/default-logging-with-stderrlog.html)) and adding the following line in the start.ini file:
--module=console-capture

I know this is only one way of solving your problem, but it worked out pretty well for me. After restarting the service, I could already see a log file in the logs subdirectory.

Comment: The link no longer works, but perhaps https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-jetty-logging covers something similar