# how to configure StdErrLog on an Embedded Jetty

Tags: groovy, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm starting a Jetty webserver from within a Groovy script. Jetty's default logging is StdErrLog. Now I'd like to configure this logging but [the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-logging.html#default-logging-with-stderrlog) only mentions how to do this when using the start.jar method to start Jetty.

How do I configure, more specifically, configure rotating log files, with StdErrLog on an embedded Jetty?

Comment: Why StdErrLog? why not configure Jetty to use java.util.logging and then configure java.util.logging to display/filter/capture what events you want?

Comment: That might be possible but I was looking specifically how to do this with StdErrLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786592/how-to-enable-logging-in-jetty). It is a few years old but should help you on your way. Additionally a page was accidentally clipped from the 9.4.x documentation that I will re-add, but you can find for now in the 9.3.x documentation [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-logging.html#configuring-jetty-logging). These [cookbook examples](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-logging-examples/tree/master/mixed-logging/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo) should also help, but again they are a few years old now.

Comment: Yeah I had already read that answer and the documentation you linked, but it only says how to switch logging implementation. It doesn't say how this would be configured in embedded mode: java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=console-capture

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts [console-capture](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-util/src/main/config/etc/console-capture.xml) is just careful application of the existing RolloverFileOutputStream to the System.setErr and System.setOut